# Why can I not define color property for a div

Tags: css, inheritance

This HTML is for a page in a mobile app, so all of the CSS styles have to be defined inline. I have a section of the page that I want to have a dark background and white text, but somehow the text is being rendered as black and I don't know why. What do I need to do to define the color property for a div? Every color:#FFFFFF definition is being ignored, in spite of the !important tag. Here is a scaled down version of the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>Test file (1)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<style>
body{background-color:#FFFFFF;}
p, blockquote, pre, ol, ul, li {color:#000000;}
h1, h2, h3 {color:#0a3454;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;">
<div class="section-wrap" style="position:relative;top:-8px;left:-8px;right:-8px;margin:auto;width:104%;padding: 0;">
    <section style="background-color: #0a3454;">
        <div style="color: #FFFFFF;">
          <div style="padding: 1.5em 0.3em 1.5em 0em; color:#FFFFFF !important; ul{color:#FFFFFF;} li{color:#FFFFFF !important;}">
            <strong><ul style="color:#FFFFFF !important;">
                <li>This text is supposed to be white but instead is black because of the initial style definition.</li>
                <li>Does anyone know why?</li>
            </ul></strong>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `ul` and `li` selectors are more specific than the color from the div and are therefore prioritized by CSS.

Remove them and the text gets white.

Demo:

```html
<head>
<title>Test file (1)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<style>
body{background-color:#FFFFFF;}
p, blockquote, pre, ol {color:#000000;}
h1, h2, h3 {color:#0a3454;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;">
<div class="section-wrap" style="position:relative;top:-8px;left:-8px;right:-8px;margin:auto;width:104%;padding: 0;">
    <section style="background-color: #0a3454;">
        <div style="color: #FFFFFF;">
          <div style="padding: 1.5em 0.3em 1.5em 0em; color:#FFFFFF !important; ul{color:#FFFFFF;} li{color:#FFFFFF !important;}">
            <strong><ul style="color:#FFFFFF !important;">
                <li>This text is supposed to be white but instead is black because of the initial style definition.</li>
                <li>Does anyone know why?</li>
            </ul></strong>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```